# How do you add and else statement to an if inside a for loop as part of a lambda using python

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, lambda, iterable

I have started learning about lambda functions in python and I like the power it has, but I have hit a wall with using if/else with a for loop in a lambda.

I know I can use the following:

```
def compare(value, compare_value):

    if value < compare_value:
        return [value, True]
    else:
        return [value, False]

number_list = [0, 1, 2, 3]
compare_number = 2

print [compare(number, compare_number) for number in number_list]
```

This I know will print:

```
[[0, True], [1, True], [2, False], [3, False]]
```

I also know I can get the same printout using this:

```
compare = lambda value, compare_value: [value, True] if value < compare_value else [value, False]

number_list = [0, 1, 2, 3]
compare_number = 2

print [compare(number, compare_number) for number in number_list]
```

I want to know if I can put all the iteration and comparison in one line. I tried the code below, python doesn't like it.

```
number_list = [0, 1, 2, 3]
compare_number = 2

print [[number, True] for number in number_list if number < compare_number else [number, False]]
```

Comment: Oh god. Please don't use a `lambda` or a "one-liner." That will be notorious. Just use a function `def`inition.

Comment: I am asking more from the viewpoint of is it possible, not I need to do it this way. Can it be done on one line?

Comment: The issue here is that there's not really any advantage to doing so. There are formatting guidelines/conventions to reduce the size of a line to 79 characters, and trying to put everything into a single line not only defies that, but will make your code much more unreadable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to complete the `if` expression before the `for number in number_list` to make it valid syntax

```
>>> print [[number, True] if number < compare_number else [number, False] for number in number_list]
[[0, True], [1, True], [2, False], [3, False]]
```

That said, this is not very readable over your original code.

Whenever you have an if statement that looks like

```
if something:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Consider replacing it with (for example)

```
return something == True
```

Or just `return something` if it's already a boolean type.

In your case, you can simplify the expression to

```
print [[number, number < compare_number] for number in number_list]
```

Comment: I generally would just replace the if statement with the boolean expression, but this was just an example I came up with to represent a similar issue that cannot be done in that way. You first code block was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
compare = lambda value, compare_value: [value, value < compare_value]
```

and

```
print [[number, number < compare_number] for number in number_list]
```

Plus what Peter Gibson says.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just use a list comprehension:

```
>>> [[n, n < compare_number] for n in number_list]
[[0, True], [1, True], [2, False], [3, False]]
```

If you want to return values other than boolean, use a ternary:

```
>>> [[n, 'a' if n < compare_number else 'b'] for n in number_list]
[[0, 'a'], [1, 'a'], [2, 'b'], [3, 'b']]
```